# No me funciona ng-init

Tags: angularjs

Tengo esto:

```
<input type='text' name="dateQualitative" ng-model="dateQualitative" 
       ng-init="dateQualitative='${valor}'" />  ===> Esto funciona
```

Pero esto otro no:

```
<div ng-show="scenario.individualQualitative" id='dateQualitative'>
    <input type='text' name="dateQualitative" ng-model="dateQualitative" 
           ng-init="dateQualitative='${valor}'" />
</div>
```

Alguna sugerencia?

**EDIT**

El codigo funciona perfectamente, es el script  de integración de DataPicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dateQualitative').datetimepicker({

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tu código funciona perfectamente. Que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: cuando esta dentro del div n-show no me sale el valor, en cambio si veo con firebug si que me sale el valor que esta en html, pero visualmente no lo veo.

Comment: ¿No te sale el valor o directamente no te sale el input? Puede igual ser problema del _ng-show_.

Comment: Me sale el input pero no veo el valor :s

Comment: @Jose Como te dije, yo probé tu código y funciona sin problemas. En ambos casos el input se llena con los datos. Quizas haya otra parte del código que este interfiriendo pero en tu caso es imposible saberlo con lo que tienes actualmente.

Comment: @devconcept tienes toda la razon, es por el script que tengo:

Comment: @Jose verifica los errores que te muestre la consola de tu navegador cuando agregas ese script

Comment: @sioesi es por el script de datetimepicker, si no relaciono el input a ese modulo si me lo muestra

Answer (score 0):

@devconcept tienes toda la razon, es por el script que tengo:

```
div ng-show="true" class='input-group date' id='dateQualitative'> 
input type='text' name="dateQualitative" 
        ng-model="dateQualitative" 
        ng-init="dateQualitative='${date}'"
            class="form-control" />
        span class="input-group-addon">
            span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        span>
/div>

script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dateQualitative').datetimepicker({
                });
    });
/script>
```

Si comento el script ya se ve el valor, estoy usando el API datetimepicker.

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Hola el error es facil, el ```datetimepicker()``` se ejecuta antes de que existan los elementos de angular.

Comment: Para corregirlo, necesitas crear una "directiva" o un "component" donde pongas el dateTImePicker en el método **link** el cual hará el efecto deseado.

Comment: @elporfitio no he podido hacerlo funcionar, me puedes dar alguna pista?

Comment: al final lo solvente con :
$('#dateQualitativeI').val('12/05/2016');